# Client not getting the collection even after autopublishing in meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor

/lib/collection.js

```
import { Mongo} from 'meteor/mongo'; 
export const Chats = new Mongo.Collection('chats');
```

/server/app.js

```
import { Chats} from '../lib/collections';

const chats = [
{
  text: 'You on your way?',

},
{
  text: 'Hey, it\'s me',

},
{
  text: 'I should buy a boat',

},
{
  text: 'Look at my mukluks!',

},
{
    text: 'This is wicked good ice cream.',
      }
];

chats.forEach(function(chat)
{
Chats.insert(chat);
})
```

/client/index.js

```
 import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';


 import {Chats} from '../lib/collections'

console.log(Chats.find());
```

Why `Chats.find()` is returning empty object?

Autopublish has not been removed. So I can't get the error.

Comment: have you forgotten to publish the collection and subscribe to it?

Comment: It won't be available on the client until after a slight delay. When you use publications you can trigger a callback on the subscription being ready which tells you that your data is now available on the client.

Answer (score 1):

This is just because the data takes a certain amount of time to reach the client. Try it like this in your `/client/index.js`

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { Tracker } from 'meteor/tracker';
import {Chats} from '../lib/collections'

Tracker.autorun( () => console.log( Chats.find() ) );
```